# Firebase onDisconnect() not working

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm having issues with Firebase's onDisconnect(). When I register `ef.onDisconnect().removeValue()` and then disconnect internet and close application (normal or force close, it doesn't matter) it will not remove value (Yes, I waited more then 5 minutes and value was still there). This is how I create firebase and register onDisconnect.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("....");
ref.onDisconnect().removeValue();
```

When I call `ref.setValue(...)` or `ref.removeValue()` it works without any problems.

Is there something wrong in sdk or should I change something?

Comment: There is no removeValue() or setValue() command. Can you try this with set() and remove() and update your example to match the results?

Comment: I am writing about java sdk and there are commands removeValue and setValue. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-presence.html first java example, there is presenceRef.onDisconnect().setValue("I was disconnected!"), I need not setValue, but removeValue and it didn't work.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the Java tag :( Are you authenticating before performing setValue()/removeValue()? The likely answer is that permissions are different at the time your onDisconnect() fires (i.e. the user in no longer authenticated or the data is in a state that doesn't allow write).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are authenticated, if the value you are changing requires authentication, and also make sure that the server has acknowledged your call to removeValue. You can verify that by adding a CompletionListener to the removeValue call: [https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/OnDisconnect.html#removeValue(com.firebase.client.Firebase.CompletionListener)](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/OnDisconnect.html#removeValue%28com.firebase.client.Firebase.CompletionListener%29)

This will let you know when the server has received the remove value request and has appropriately queued it up.